# Hibernate issues

Tags: 15.04, hibernate, i915

I am not being able to setup Hibernation on my ubuntu please help.
I have ubuntu gnome 15.04 and I have installed pm utils I have tried command sudo pm-hibernate and the computer does go to hibernate but not in one go first it produces errors like unable to freeze process etc then it goes to hibernate on running the command the second time. When I boot again it does not resume.

Comment: Not all computers work well with hibernate. Upgrading bios may help.

Answer (score 0):

answered here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

if hibernate works, then set it by default by editing/creating:

/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
```

the first block made my machine hibernate once, but when I restarted it stopped working, the second block makes sure it keeps working